# Mongodb - Substract dates

Tags: mongodb, date, nosql, subtraction

I have the following database

```
{ "_id" : 1, "time" : "Nov 26, 2021 14:06:30.092158000"}
...
...
{ "_id" : 9999, "time" : "Nov 27, 2021 12:45:01.134957000" }*
```

I want to subtract dates Nov 27, 2021 12:45:01.134957000 -  Nov 26, 2021 14:06:30.092158000 (last date - initial date) and get the result in seconds.

Any recommendation?

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as strings, it's a design flaw! Store always proper `Date` objects, then you can simply use [$dateSubtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateSubtract/) or even plain `-` which returns the difference in Milliseconds

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, the dataset comes from a csv file  that exports python. For future projects, how would I have to export the date from python?

Comment: Transform it to [datetime](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/datetimes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little update script to convert those nasty datestrings into nice datetimes in MongoDB:

```
var mmap = {"Jan":"01", "Feb":"02", "Mar":"03", "Apr":"04", "May":"05", "Jun":"06",
            "Jul":"07", "Aug":"08", "Sep":"09", "Oct":"10", "Nov":"11", "Dec":"12"};
db.foo.find().forEach(function(d) {
    var zz = d['time'].split(' '); // ['Nov','26,','2021','15:06:30.092158000']                          
    print(zz);

    // Turns 4, into 04 and 27, into 27.  Sort of like %02d:                                             
    var day = ("00" + zz[1].substring(0,zz[1].length-1) ).slice(-2)

    var dd = new ISODate(zz[2] + '-' + mmap[zz[0]] + '-'
                         + day
                         + 'T' + zz[3].substring(0,12) // MongoDB can only store millis                  
                         + 'Z');

    // So as not to lose info, let's capture the nanos as an int:                                                 
    var nanos = new NumberInt(zz[3].substring(9,18));

    db.foo.update({_id:d['_id']},{$set: {"time":dd, "nanos":nanos}});
});
```

Once you have real dates, everything becomes easy.  Here a generalized way to get a set of docs based on some filtering criteria, then getting first and last date and finding the diff.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
//  Put $match and other filtering expressions here if desired.                                          

    {$sort: {"time":1}}  // Get them in order...                                                         
    // ... and take first and last items!                                                                
    ,{$group: {_id: null, fd: {$first:"$time"}, ld: {$last:"$time"}}}
    ,{$addFields: {diff: {$subtract: ["$ld","$fd"]}}}
]);
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel I would rather suggest library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or similar: `{ $set: { time: moment(d.time, "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS").toDate()) } }`